# Here is my code for checking the angle between two sets of vectors. Need someone to check it

Tags: python, numpy, math

the following simple code for checking an angle, which is supposed to be in degree, between two sets of vectors.

Can you tell me that the code is correct and it is giving the result in degree?

For example, let

```
v1= [-0.89169092  0.02074738 -0.45216906]
v2 = [-0.8866975   0.08203217 -0.45501457]
```

According to the code the degree difference is 3.52732357. Is the code giving the correct result? I mean in degree?

```
import math
def angle(v1,v2):
    unit_vector_1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)
    unit_vector_2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
    dot_product = np.dot(unit_vector_1, unit_vector_2)
    return np.arccos(dot_product)
a = angle(v1,v2)
deg = np.rad2deg(a)
print(deg)
```

Comment: use an [online checker](https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/angl/) to verify your code.

Comment: if the parameters v1 and v2 are array types, then the program should crash at unit_vector_1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1). Because its not possible to divide arrays.

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to know that, what is dot product and what is cross product?
Then you can search about "angle between two vectors". So you will get formulas i.e [formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20get%20angle%20between%20two%20vectors&client=ubuntu&hs=sHF&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALiCzsYBERNeb-soUPKR7bEVdU3TvDIOtQ:1666114817558&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR0Ouuqer6AhWWQ_EDHb2mAS4Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=968&dpr=1#imgrc=4KeinIXXI-XlCM)

The function does only dot product.

Comment: Well, I know dot and cross products. But just to be absolutely sure, I'm asking other people's opinion. I checked with https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/angl/ as some people proposed and it seems the code is correct.
But I just need other people's assurance.